# Finding the positions and lengths of gaps (indels) in a sequence alignment with Python

Tags: python

I am currently learning python. I do not want to use Biopython, or really any imported modules, other than maybe regex so I can understand what the code is doing.

From a genetic sequence alignment, I would like to find the location of the start and end positions of gaps/indels "-" that are next to each other within my sequences, the number of gap regions, and calculate the length of gap regions. For example:

```
>Seq1
ATC----GCTGTA--A-----T
```

I would like an output that may look something like this:

```
Number of gaps = 3

Index Position of Gap region 1 = 3 to 6
Length of Gap region 1 = 4

Index Position of Gap region 2 = 13 to 14
Length of Gap region 2 = 2

Index Position of Gap region 3 = 16 to 20
Length of Gap region 3 = 5
```

I have tried to figure this out on larger sequence alignments but I have not been able to even remotely figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is to use regular expression to find a gap (one or more dashes, which translate to '-+', the plus sign means *one or more*):

```
import re

seq = 'ATC----GCTGTA--A-----T'
matches = list(re.finditer('-+', seq))

print 'Number of gaps =', len(matches)
print

for region_number, match in enumerate(matches, 1):
    print 'Index Position of Gap region {} = {} to {}'.format(
            region_number,
            match.start(),
            match.end() - 1)
    print 'Length of Gap region {} = {}'.format(
            region_number,
            match.end() - match.start())
    print
```

## Notes

- `matches` is a list of match objects
- In order to get the region number, I used the function `enumerate`. You can look it up to see how it works.
- The match object has many methods, but we are interested in `.start()` which returns the start index and `.end()` which return the end index. Note that the *end index* here is one more that what you want, thus I subtracted 1 from it.

Comment: Indeed a fully appropriate solution. Congratulations, even if it is OK only for Python 2. You need only to add parenthesis to `print` arguments in order to be also compatible with Python 3,

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my suggestion of code, quite straight-forward, short and easy to understand, without any other imported package other than `re`:

```
import re

def findGaps(aSeq):
    # Get and print the list of gaps present into the sequence
    gaps = re.findall('[-]+', aSeq)
    print('Number of gaps = {0} \n'.format(len(gaps)))
    # Get and print start index, end index and length for each gap
    for i,gap in enumerate(gaps,1):
        startIndex = aSeq.index(gap)
        endIndex = startIndex + len(gap) - 1
        print('Index Position of Gap region {0} = {1} to {2}'.format(i, startIndex, endIndex))
        print('Length of Gap region {0} = {1} \n'.format(i, len(gap)))
        aSeq = aSeq.replace(gap,'*' * len(gap), 1)

findGaps("ATC----GCTGTA--A-----T")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my take on this problem:

```
import itertools

nucleotide='ATC----GCTGTA--A-----T'
# group the repeated positions
gaps = [(k, sum(1 for _ in vs)) for k, vs in itertools.groupby(nucleotide)]

# text formating
summary_head = "Number of gaps = {0}"
summary_gap = """
Index Position of Gap region {0} = {2} to {3}
Length of Gap region {0} = {1}
"""

# Print output
print summary_head.format(len([g for g in gaps if g[0]=="-"]))
gcount = 1   # this will count the gap number
position = 0 # this will make sure we know the position in the sequence
for i, g in enumerate(gaps):
    if g[0] == "-":
        gini = position             # start position current gap
        gend = position + g[1] - 1  # end position current gap
        print summary_gap.format(gcount, g[1], gini, gend)
        gcount+=1
    position += g[1]
```

This generates your expected output:

```
# Number of gaps = 3

# Index Position of Gap region 1 = 3 to 6
# Length of Gap region 1 = 4

# Index Position of Gap region 2 = 13 to 14
# Length of Gap region 2 = 2

# Index Position of Gap region 3 = 16 to 20
# Length of Gap region 3 = 5
```

**EDIT: ALTERNATIVE WITH PANDAS**

```
import itertools
import pandas as pd

nucleotide='ATC----GCTGTA--A-----T'
# group the repeated positions
gaps = pd.DataFrame([(k, sum(1 for _ in vs)) for k, vs in itertools.groupby(nucleotide)])

gaps.columns = ["type", "length"]
gaps["ini"] = gaps["length"].cumsum() - gaps["length"]
gaps["end"] = gaps["ini"] + gaps["length"] - 1
gaps = gaps[gaps["type"] == "-"]
gaps.index = range(1, gaps.shape[0] + 1)

summary_head = "Number of gaps = {0}"

summary_gap = """
Index Position of Gap region {0} = {1[ini]} to {1[end]}
Length of Gap region {0} = {1[length]}
"""

print summary_head.format(gaps.shape[0])

for index, row in gaps.iterrows():
    print summary_gap.format(index, row)
```

This alternative has the benefit that if you are analyzing multiple sequences you can add the sequence identifier as an extra column and have all the data from all your sequences in a single data structure; something like this:

```
import itertools
import pandas as pd

nucleotides=['>Seq1\nATC----GCTGTA--A-----T',
             '>Seq2\nATCTCC---TG--TCGGATG-T']
all_gaps = []
for nucleoseq in nucleotides:
    seqid, nucleotide = nucleoseq[1:].split("\n")
    gaps = pd.DataFrame([(k, sum(1 for _ in vs)) for k, vs in itertools.groupby(nucleotide)])

    gaps.columns = ["type", "length"]
    gaps["ini"] = gaps["length"].cumsum() - gaps["length"]
    gaps["end"] = gaps["ini"] + gaps["length"] - 1
    gaps = gaps[gaps["type"] == "-"]
    gaps.index = range(1, gaps.shape[0] + 1)
    gaps["seqid"] = seqid
    all_gaps.append(gaps)
all_gaps = pd.concat(all_gaps)
print(all_gaps)
```

will generate a data container with:

```
  type  length  ini  end seqid
1    -       4    3    6  Seq1
2    -       2   13   14  Seq1
3    -       5   16   20  Seq1
1    -       3    6    8  Seq2
2    -       2   11   12  Seq2
3    -       1   20   20  Seq2
```

that you can format afterwards like:

```
for k in all_gaps["seqid"].unique():
    seqg = all_gaps[all_gaps["seqid"] == k]
    print ">{}".format(k)
    print summary_head.format(seqg.shape[0])

    for index, row in seqg.iterrows():
        print summary_gap.format(index, row)
```

which can look like:

```
>Seq1
Number of gaps = 3

Index Position of Gap region 1 = 3 to 6
Length of Gap region 1 = 4

Index Position of Gap region 2 = 13 to 14
Length of Gap region 2 = 2

Index Position of Gap region 3 = 16 to 20
Length of Gap region 3 = 5

>Seq2
Number of gaps = 3

Index Position of Gap region 1 = 6 to 8
Length of Gap region 1 = 3

Index Position of Gap region 2 = 11 to 12
Length of Gap region 2 = 2

Index Position of Gap region 3 = 20 to 20
Length of Gap region 3 = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a longer-winded way about this than with regex, but you could find the index of the hyphens and group them by using first-differences:

```
>>> def get_seq_gaps(seq):
...     gaps = np.array([i for i, el in enumerate(seq) if el == '-'])
...     diff = np.cumsum(np.append([False], np.diff(gaps) != 1))
...     un = np.unique(diff)
...     yield len(un)
...     for i in un:
...         subseq = gaps[diff == i]
...         yield i + 1, len(subseq), subseq.min(), subseq.max()

>>> def report_gaps(seq):
...     gaps = get_seq_gaps(seq)
...     print('Number of gaps = %s\n' % next(gaps), sep='')
...     for (i, l, mn, mx) in gaps:
...         print('Index Position of Gap region %s = %s to %s' % (i, mn, mx))
...         print('Length of Gap Region %s = %s\n' % (i, l), sep='')

>>> seq = 'ATC----GCTGTA--A-----T'
>>> report_gaps(seq)
Number of gaps = 3

Index Position of Gap region 1 = 3 to 6
Length of Gap Region 1 = 4

Index Position of Gap region 2 = 13 to 14
Length of Gap Region 2 = 2

Index Position of Gap region 3 = 16 to 20
Length of Gap Region 3 = 5
```

First, this forms an array of the indices at which you have hyphens:

```
>>> gaps
array([ 3,  4,  5,  6, 13, 14, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20])
```

Places where first differences are not 1 indicate breaks.  Throw on another False to maintain length.

```
>>> diff
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2])
```

Now take the unique elements of these groups, constrain `gaps` to the corresponding indices, and find its min/max.